# How to make a TextView's text to be underlined?

Tags: android

There is a `TextView` :

```
TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
```

This `TextView` has a `text`.

How to make its `text` to be `underlined` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do underline,

1. Use spannable object as,

   ```
   String data="Underlined Text";
   SpannableString content = new SpannableString(data);
   content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, data.length(), 0);
   mTextView.setText(content);
   ```
2. Use Html.fromhtml()

   ```
   String htmlStr="<u>Underlined Text</u>";
   mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlStr));
   ```
3. You can make use of setPaintFlags method of TextView

   ```
   mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
   mTextView.setText("Underlined Text");
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Spannable` object. You can find the documentation for the [UnderlineSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan.html) here

```
String text = "your text";
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(text);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, text.length(), 0);
tabTitle.setText(content);
```

Comment: How will it be applied to the TextView ?

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved if you are using a [string resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#stringresources) xml file, which supports HTML tags like ,  and .

```
<resource>
    <string name="your_string">This is an <u>underline</u> content.</string>
</resources>
```

If you want to underline something from code use:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Content");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
textView.setText(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView.setPaintFlags(TextView.getPaintFlags() |  Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: it is the simplest way :) but the others answers are also good :)

Answer (score 1):

TextView also supports HTML:

```
String text = "<font color=#ff0000><b><u>"+ "My Demo Text" +"</b </u></font>";
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```